# Deserialize Record - how to init missing properties

Tags: c#, json.net, record

Consider a simple case of trying to deserialize a *record* where some properties are missing:

```
#nullable enable

record Rec(int Age, Employee Employee); // Employee has a default constructor

var rec = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rec>("{\"Age\":30}");
```

I get `rec` with Employee set to null without any compiler warning despite `nullable enabled` and have to manually set it using the default constructor.

Is there a way to tell `DeserializeObject` to try/use the default constructor for missing properties instead of setting them to null ?

Comment: no nullability as a requirement? You might need to explain yourself sir, this as a design pattern could lead to some interesting workarounds needed at a lot of levels...

Comment: what I mean is that with #nullable enable I expect to not have Employee as null without some compiler warning which I don't get in this case. But yes confusing I'm editing my question.

Comment: I was going to provide an answer, there is a way with classes, but I'm not sure about the semantics involved with records and de-serialization.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller records like above will simply have a single constructor `RecRec(int Age, Employee Employee) { thisd.Age=Age; this.Employee=Employee; }`

Comment: I think you'll have to use the verbose syntax, so you can declare the default implementation, but haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Are you aware of the serialization callbacks:  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbackAttributes.htm

Answer (score 2):

There is an [overload to `DeserializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_3.htm) that allows you to pass in an array of `JsonConverter` which allows you to management the type conversion (from JObject) yourself. Alternatively you could also change the default `JsonSerializerSettings` to **NOT** allow nulls and manually handle the exception that is raised.

> All of that would require a lot of boilerplate code but for simple default type instantiation, there is a `CustomCreationConverter` you can inherit from

```
class RecConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Rec>
{
    public override Rec Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new Rec ( 0, new Employee() { Name = "Custom" } );
    }
}
```

> Note that the default value of properties is usually defined in the declaration of the type itself.

`DeserializeObject` will first instantiate the object, and then if MissingMemberHandling is set to "Ignore", it only sets the properties that are available, the others will remain in their default initialized state, that is defined by the default constructor for that type, which may be defined through auto-property initialization syntax.

You could declare your class with default initialization for the properties that you require to be non-null:

```
public class Rec
{
    public int Age { get;set; }
    public Employee Employee { get;set; } = new Employee();
}
```

Similar rules apply for C#9 `record`, however `DeserializeObject` will call the relevant constructor that matches the arguments that are available from the JSON string, so you can use the verbose declaration syntax to achieve the same thing:

```
record Rec
{
    public int Age { get;init; }
    public Employee Employee { get;init; } = new Employee();
}
```

See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Dmpmn5

Comment: ok great, but if you look at my question I am was wondering if there is a way to specify this in call to DeserializeObject ?

Comment: I see it, and immediately cringed... you would have to write your own `JsonConvert` implementation which would be a lot of code and sort of defeats the point of using records to reduce and simplify the syntax of an immutable class

Comment: I posted this feature request - https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2519

Comment: No you've missed the point, the default state of the record should be part of the record definition, or part of your custom code that manages serialization, not a special generic feature of a serialization pipeline that already provides the necessary mechanisms. This is nothing special or new with records, the same thing applies to classes. I would immediately vote against adding this somehow as a generic aspect of serialization, it would break or adversely affect too many existing implementations, all of my apps would suddenly start populating new empty records all over the place

Comment: What is the point of an immutable default instance of a nested object in your record? This is a clear X,Y issue. The issue that you should resolve is in the logic that processes these records, not in the deserialization itself.

Comment: This question is not about records, I just used a record cause it was shorter, the suggestion will not break anything unless used (that is explicitly given to  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`)

Comment: You shouldn't have used records then, it is misleading, and only 2 lines shorter. To what level should such a setting operate on though, you could end up with a deep nested object graph of pre-initialized object instances, all self referencing links would be broken or non determinate. In all my applications, where it is valid for the object to be pre-initialized with a default value, you put that information in the class definition itself. Serialization should be to go to and from text, it shouldn't inject any information that was not previously available.

Comment: I appreciate he comments - what do you mean by "self referencing links" ? broken how ? ps records are useful here because the main advantage is when using the short form without having to write a ctor which is a major reason to use records in the first place (think about records with many entries and constant refactoring ie adding/removing fields without having to modify the ctor which is bug prone)

Comment: auto properties with default initializers means that those issues you cite pretty much don't exist anymore. I wish you well on your journey, but it sounds like you're going about things backwards, or at least the really hard way.

Comment: @kofifus this got me thinking, so I've posted a response to your github issue and included an example of the converter implementation in this post, I think the `CustomCreationConverter` is what you are looking for.